# extjs 4 line chart rendering problems

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4

I am having trouble with extjs rendering the line chart below. Specifically, the last six values are null which are (correctly) not shown on the series line but (incorrectly) have a marker dot displayed for them (see top right of the image below).

[image: line chart with bad rendering]

I am pulling the graph data from a database as json:

```
// data store fields
Ext.define('Graphs', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'the_quota',     type: 'int'},
        {name: 'count_pt_year', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'date_string',   type: 'string'}
    ]
});

// get the graph data
var graphStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Graphs',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'sqlRequest.jsp?queryName=events_getGraph',
        timeout: 160000,
        reader: 'json'
    },
    autoLoad:false
});
```

If I change the query to return these null values as blanks instead (`''`) then the json reader converts them to zeros and the values display as zero along the bottom of the graph *with* a series line, which is worse then having the markers plastered to the ceiling without a series line.

I haven't been able to find any config option in `Ext.chart.Series` to hide null values on the graph. Nor have I been able to find a config option in `Ext.data.Store` to return blanks as blanks and not "0".

Looking for some other workaround.

Or has anyone resolved these issues from within the library itself (ext-all.js)?

Comment: While I agree that the display looks bad, how would you expect null values to display, as a gap in the line? Seems strange that null would be a valid value in a chart like this.

Comment: @bmoeskau "Seems strange that null would be a valid value in a chart like this." That was my feeling on this. Yes wanted it to display as a gap. That is, the six dots at the top-right of the graph (null values) should not be there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a config option under `Ext.data.Field` called `useNull`. If the data received cannot be parsed into a number, `null` will be used instead. As of right now I can't recall if that alone will fix the problem, and I have a memory of once using a custom convert function that went something like this:

```
convert: function(value){
    if(typeof value !=== 'number') // or other similar conversion
        return undefined;
    return value;
}
```

If this doesn't work, you may need to customize your store/reader to completely exclude records containing the undesirable `null` value.

EDIT - Using `useNull` looks like this: `{name: 'someName', type: 'int', useNull: true}`

Comment: Thanks Eric, **convert:** solved it. **useNull:** did not work, it seems extjs line charts display "null" or "NaN" data as shown in my image above but "undefined" data will not show up on a line graph.

Comment: One issue I ran into on implementation was that I had to remove the Ext.data.Model type cast: **type: 'int'** before it would work. This was because the type cast converted the null or blanks to a number before the convert function would execute and it always returned as zero until I removed it.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. And now I have a definite reference for the next time I run into this.

Comment: As of Ext JS 4.2.1, `useNull` still doesn't seem to work.  Your `convert` function was the savior.  Thanks!