# ExtJs 4.1.1 chart missing markers

Tags: extjs, charts, series

I spent days trying to solve this one:

I'm trying to create a chart with several series. In one series I show a line with all points (in my code "val" series). In the second series I wish to show only part of the points ("temperature" series). Both series are showing a data type of int.

I tried to set a very low value to the "temperature" field in order to omit it from the chart but it also caused the respective "val" to be skipped!

**In ExtJs 4.1.1: The 10am value of the "val" field is skipped.**

**In ExtJs 4.0.7: The 10am value of the "val" field exists!**

(I wish I could post images here but I do not have 10 reputation points.:-( )

Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('WeatherPoint', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['temperature', 'date', 'val']
});

var store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'WeatherPoint',
    data: [
        { temperature: 58, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 8), val: 10 },
        { temperature: 63, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 9), val: 20 },
        { temperature: -100, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 10), val: 40 }, 
        { temperature: 78, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 11), val: 90 },
        { temperature: 81, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 12), val: 50 }
    ]
}); 

var chart1 = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart',{
        xtype: 'chart',
        animate: false,
        store: store1,
        legend: true,
        insetPadding: 30,
        axes: [{
            title: 'Temperature',
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'left',
            fields: ['temperature', 'val'],
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 100
        }, {
            title: 'Time',
            type: 'Time',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['date'],
            dateFormat: 'ga',
            step: [Ext.Date.HOUR, 1],
            fromDate: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 8),
            toDate: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 12)
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'scatter',
            axis: ['left','bottom'],
            xField: 'date',
            yField: 'temperature'
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            title: 'val',
            axis: ['left','bottom'],
            xField: 'date',
            yField: 'val'
        }]
    });


var panel1 = Ext.create('widget.panel', {
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: 'fit',
    items: chart1
});
```

1. Why 4.1.1 makes all series skip because of a value that is out-of-range in one series?
2. How can I show only part of the points in one series and all of the point in the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `null` or empty `''` values for points you want to hide.

**Example:**

```
var store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'WeatherPoint',
    data: [
        { temperature: 58, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 8), val: 10 },
        { temperature: 63, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 9), val: 20 },
        { temperature: '', date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 10), val: 40 },
        { temperature: 78, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 11), val: ''},
        { temperature: 81, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 12), val: 50 }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Colombo. It works. The only problem is that it log a warning to the console for every record that has a null or '' value.

Comment: set useNull: true in field definitions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595535/extjs-4-line-chart-rendering-problems

Comment: Great!! I did it and changed all occurrences of a missing value to 0 (because 0 in int/float field is considered a null) and it worked well without warnings. Thank you again, Colombo :-)