# Extjs Line Chart multiline label

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4, linechart

I want to make a label in Line Chart on X axis, that shows summary for selected category. I want to format this, so under category name I have values. It works if I do:

```
return Ext.Date.format(v, 'M Y') + '\r' + 
(val.data.Budgeted==null?'':('$ '+Ext.util.Format.number(val.data.Budgeted, '0,000') + '\r')) +
(val.data.Actual==null?'':('$ '+Ext.util.Format.number(val.data.Actual, '0,000') + '\r'));
```

still, label is going down, as I found, with each \r char. So if I have no \r it shows like it should, but if there is N '\r'-s then label itself will go down as there is N lines of text over it.

Also will be nice to find a way to format text (align)

EDIT:
I found a way to do this, by changing "drawVerticalLabels" function in axis config. Still, it's a bad way in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something pretty similar I think. There's a screenshot of it on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8595535/1062992).

I ended up doing it like an HTML template. I wasn't as familiar with the ExtJS framework as I am now so if I had to redo it I would probably use an xtemplate, but this worked out for me:

```
series: [{
    type: 'line',
    title: 'This Year',
    axis: 'left',
    smooth: false,
    xField: 'date_value',
    yField: 'the_count',

    // custom tips
    tips: {
      trackMouse: true,
      width: 127,
      height: 70,
      hideDelay: 0,
      dismissDelay: 0,
      renderer: function(record) {
        this.setTitle('<table width=115><tr><th><b>' + 
            record.get('date_value') + 
            ':</b></th><td align=right>' + 
            record.get('the_count') + 
            '</td></tr><tr><th><b>Quota:</b></th><td align=right>' + 
            record.get('the_quota') +
            '</td></tr><tr><th><b>Diff:</b></th><td align=right>' +
            (record.get('the_quota') > record.get('the_count') ? 
                '-' + (record.get('the_quota') - record.get('the_count')) :
                '+' + (record.get('the_count') - record.get('the_quota'))
            ) + '</td></tr></table>'
        );
      }
    }
}]
```

Comment: I don't want it to be tips, which I have already. I want the labels of X axis be multilined

Answer (score 0):

Multiline can be done with inserting '\n' for line break in the axis renderer, and by default it is centered.